# Can landlord force tenant to pay only online in NH

Tags: landlord, tenant, rent, payment, new-hampshire

I've been a tenant for over 5 years in NH, paying rent early (mid-month) via automatic payments from my bank (i.e. check sent from my bank).  I don't need to think about it, it is auto-scheduled every month.

I just got a notice asking tenants to use a home-grown portal to pay via Bank E-Check or Credit/Debit card (extra fee).  My assumption is that the Bank E-Check is a ACH, which means that after I authorize, they can pull money from my account.  I am also worried about cyber security with all the data breaches that have happened with far more prepared sites (i.e. Target, etc).  In general, I strongly prefer to pay everything from my bank out, I don't have bills pull from the account.

My questions is, can they legally force me to use their portal?
They "intend to enforce accepting only online payments in the very near future"

Additional info: my lease terms don't specify how the rent shall be paid, but does say that pro-rate amount shall be paid by check or money order.

I can't go and talk to them in person due to office being closed.  And they aren't responsive generally to phone or email.

A quick search looked like in NH the leasing agent can do whatever they want.

Thoughts?

Comment: A Bank E-Check does not necessarily mean that you authorize and they pull. Most likely it means that you setup periodic outgoing payment that  you can then stop any time. It's 2020 now. Catch up.

Answer (score 1):

### A contract can specify the allowed method(s) of payment

If your contract doesn’t then payment by cash is acceptable or any other method the vendor accepts. Your landlord can choose to accept checks and then, they can choose to no longer accept them. Your choice is to either pay in cash or by a method they do accept.